# Illegal parameter number glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries-extra

This code does not compile with my tectonic latex compiler. On overleaf it compiles, but it complains about same error with message it fixed it with replacing # with ##. I don't know latex very well but this seems like bug to me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{psi}{name=\ensuremath\overleftarrow f, description={left arrow}}

\begin{document}
    \printunsrtglossary
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `\protect` before `\overleftarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{psi}{name={\(\protect\overleftarrow{f}\)}, description={left arrow}}

\begin{document}
    \printunsrtglossary
\end{document}
```